Troubleshooting HTTP 500.19 Error: Invalid Configuration Data
The file path for web.config is specified as '?\C:\inetpub...' while attempting to upload a .NET 7 API to an IIS server. error code: 0x8007000d
enter image description here
I've attempted to edit permissions, change the pipeline, and adjust the .NET version, but the issue persists.

Yes, but it doesn't work. There should be this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778402/iis-not-able-to-locate-the-web-config, but I can't find that file (applicationhost.config) in Visual Studio 2022
